# Stopping a DDoS attack on Tor daemon

Tags: configuration, onion-services, attacks

I've already check [How to protect a hidden service against DDOS attack?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/how-to-protect-a-hidden-service-against-ddos-attack) and [How to deal with DDOS attacks?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13786/how-to-deal-with-ddos-attacks) and [How to mitigate layer 7 attacks on hidden services?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8819/how-to-mitigate-layer-7-attacks-on-hidden-services?rq=1). The problem is not DDoS of web server, instead DDoS of Tor daemon. I already looked at http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/777-Stopping-Tor-Attacks.html. I customised his solution to fit my needs. It worked for short time, but then stopped working. I tried change the detector of bots, but not work. The Tor hangs then crash. When pull Tor back online, same attack.

I already deploy OnionBalance servers with a script that load balance instance of Tor on multicore processors.

I still get destroy by a DDoS attack. Anyone have any solutions? Tor Project need fix this soon.

Comment: Hi, you never got back to us on #tor and you've not provided *any* of the information that we asked for there in this question either. This seems like a bad-faith effort on your part. Also HackerFactor is a moron and his patch is going to waste more of your CPU clockcycles than it will spare you. Remove the patches, provide us the requested logs and information, then we can actually do something. Your idle speculation based on some dipshits blogpost about issues he doesn't understand is confusing you more than helping you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the kind comment I realised Tor on my Whonix Gateway was out of date when talking to some people in IRC. I deleted the Gateway and reinstalled with the newest version of Tor to remove HackerFactor's changes.

This seems to have fixed the problem, and everything is running smoothly now. For reference this is the same issue I was having: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/20203

My apologies.